# Editing and Updating XML based on condition using Shell Script

Tags: xml, shell, unix

I want to change a value (i.e., `value="false"`) using Shell Script. How could I go about doing that. Please provide me with any suggestion.

***What I have tried / used:***

I used command-> `sed 's/true/false/g' ml.xml`.

***Problem:***

But all `true` content changed.

***What I would like:***

My requirement entails that only *a certain specific* content to be changed, not every content.

Before: `property name="s" value="true"`

After: `property name="s" value="false"`

### ml.file

```
<bean id="a"
    class="com.s.analyzer.Analyzer" scope="singleton">
    <!--  *** CHANGE to true for first daily run, otherwise false *** -->
    <property name="s" value="true" />

    <property name="a1l" value="2.5" />
    <property name="mi" value="2000" />
    <property name="ma" value="1" />
</bean>
```

Comment: that's like parsing html with regexes. just don't. pick a suitable programming language.

Comment: Although it can be done using `sed`, I will recommend using an xml parser. `python` has `elementTree`. To use `sed` you would use `sed -i '/<bean id="a"/,+3{s/^\(.*property name="s" value=\)"[^"]*}\(.*\)$/\1"False"\2/}' ml.xml`.

Comment: just use something like python or perl.

Answer (score 0):

This is an exact match (of `<property name="s" value="true`):

```
sed  -e "s/\(<property name=\"s\" value=\"\)true/\1false/g"  file
```

To change the file inplace:

```
sed  -i "s/\(<property name=\"s\" value=\"\)true/\1false/g"  file
```

If you want an exact match of `<property name="s" value="true" />`, then:

```
sed  -e "s/\(<property name=\"s\" value=\"\)true\(\" \/>\)/\1false\2/g"  file
```

Comment: put your xml file path instead of `file` in my  answer

Comment: Actually I am new to shell script. And a just beginner to So please  can you provide some link which is helpful for me

Comment: If you are going for bash, start from reading the manual first:www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html

Answer (score 0):

Using xml tools would be much better here. See for example how to do this with xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet ed --ps --inplace --update '//bean/property[@name="s"]/@value' -v false ml.xml
```